# How to create matrix with specific value in lower triangle and rest values are zero in python?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I am trying to create a matrix of size timesteps x timesteps, which for four timesteps in dense form looks like this:

```
   M = (1 0 0 0
        1 1 0 0
        1 1 1 0
        1 1 1 1)
```

For a certain number of timesteps I can create dense matrices as follows:

```
    import scipy.sparse as sp
    import numpy as np

    ld = np.ones((timesteps, timesteps))
    ld = np.tril(ld)
    ld_sparse=sp.coo_matrix(ld)
```

However, I need this matrix for timesteps = 35136, which causes a Numpy Memory Error. For this reason I tried to create the matrix using scipy sparse, but I couldn't find a function with which to do this.
Thats why I tried to build an array for row, col and data with for loop what is very inefficient.

```
    row=np.array([])
    column=row=np.array([])
    data=row=np.array([])

    for t in list(range(timesteps)):
      row=np.append(row,np.full((1,(t+1)),t))
      column = np.append(column, np.arange(t + 1))
      data = np.append(data, np.full((1, (t + 1)), 1))

    ld=sp.coo_matrix((data,(row,column)), shape=(timesteps,timesteps))
```

The final goal is to create a constraint matrix for a linear optimization problem. The matrix "ld" should be used as a submatrix to describe the energy flow of a battery storage. The different submatrices are then combined to the whole constraint matrix. As explained above I could not find an efficient way to create the submatrix "ld".

```
     lm=sp.identity(timesteps)
     om=sp.coo_matrix((timesteps,timesteps))
     ov=sp.coo_matrix((timesteps,1))
     lv = sp.coo_matrix(np.ones(timesteps).reshape(timesteps, 1))
     ov = sp.coo_matrix((timesteps, 1))
     value = step_duration ** (-1)
     tv = sp.coo_matrix(np.full((timesteps, 1), value))

    A=sp.bmat([
[lm,lm,lm,lm,om,ov,ov],
[lm,om,om,om,om,ov,ov],
[om,om,om,lm,lm,ov,ov],
[om,-lm,om,om,om,ov,ov],
[om,om,lm,om,om,-lv,ov],
[om,om,-lm,om,om,-lv,ov],
[om,om,ld,om,om,ov,-tv],
[om,om,-ld,om,om,ov,ov],
[om,om,om,om,om,ov,-lv]])
```

Comment: How do you plan to use this matrix? You may want to update the question to reflect your final goal. The matrix you describe is easy to define and difficult to store explicitly; this often indicates that there is a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is my first post on stackoverflow. I edited the problem description. Feel free to ask if something is not to understand.

Comment: Repeated `np.append` is inefficient.  List append is better.  Do one `hstack` at the end.  But I don't see how sparse matrix will help with memory. It's not sparse enough.

Comment: If you are using a model definition library to solve the LP, you might check if it can take advantage of sparsity. Julia package JuMP does this, and it seems that Pyomo does as well.

Answer (score 0):

`MemoryError` comes from the default element type in `np.ones`, which is `numpy.float64`. Just use another `dtype`, like `bool`:

```
ld = np.ones((35136, 35136), dtype=bool)
```

Every boolean value is 1 byte instead of 8 in the default case, and this should easily fit in memory.